# Return a sublist after searching a string?

Tags: java, arraylist

I had this method `public ArrayList<Rentals> search(String t)`, which is part of a class that manages the movies rentals list. Based on the string passed as an explicit parameter, the method must return all movies that contain the string in the title. The method does the search, but I don't know how to get back the sublist that contains all the movies that have that string in the name.

Comment: I assume the return statement would help. no doubt you already have one, otherwise you would run into compilation issues. How about showing us the relevant code?

Comment: Create a new list. Add matching titles to the new list. Return the new list.

Answer (score 0):

1. "Old-style" solution
   Here a resulting list is created, an input list is iterated with `for-each` loop, the movie title is matched to contain the search words, and added to the resulting list if matched.  Then the list is returned.

```java
List<Rentals> mainList = new ArrayList<>(); // populated somewhere else

public List<Rentals> search(String title) {
    List<Rentals> subList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Rentals rental : mainList) {
        if (rental.getTitle().contains(title)) { // the simplest search
            subList.add(rental);
        }
    }
    return subList;
}
```

2. Using Stream API
   `List<Rentals>` may be converted into `Stream<Rentals>` which is then filtered by the condition and the result is collected into a new list in a more concise way:

```java
public List<Rentals> search(String title) {
    return mainList.stream()
                   .filter(rental -> rental.getTitle().contains(title))
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```